# Apply reverse of CSS animation

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I have a div and some component state representing whether or not that div is opened or closed.

When the state is `!open`, the component is hidden by `display: none`

When state changes to `open`, the component is now shown by changing to `display: block`

I slide the element into the screen. I do that through a keyframe animation.

```css
@keyframes slide-in {
    0% {
        left: -100vw;
    }
    100% {
        left: 0;
    }
}
```

```html
<div style={{ animation: slide-in 1s, display: open ? 'block' : 'none', position: 'absolute'}}>
   This slides open when state is changed to open.
</div>
```

This works great when I'm going from closed -> open. However, there's no animation at all for when I go from open -> closed. Which is slightly jarring. I tried but could not find a simple way to do this - so many ridiculous answers with hacky visibility changes or JS event listeners and class name changing.

I find it impossible to believe there's a very simple way to go one direction, but not the other, when usually you want both.

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: `left` doesn't have any effect on a `static`-ally positioned element. Are you sure this is all your code?

Comment: yeah, didn't include non-pertinent styling. the slide-in works - I'm only asking how to get it to slide out without adding in a bunch of extra logic.

Comment: How the element is positioned might be relevant, for example is its position to affect other elements. If not, consider translate rather than left and use a transition.

Answer (score 1):

You can play an animation in reverse by setting [`animation-direction`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation-direction), but it seems more like you want a transition?

```css
.slide-open {
  transition: left 1s;
  left: -100vw;
}

.slide-open.open {
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div className=`slide-open ${open ? 'open' : ''}`>
   This slides open when state is changed to open.
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

How about setting the position `not using the absolute left and right` value, but using transition? It's more advisable to use css transition when applying an animation